# How to make function calls with ES6 template literals

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

UPDATE:
Here is a better example;
My code is

```
let myFunction = () => {

    console.log('Yo');
    alert('Yo');

}

let About = {

    render : async () => {

        return /*html*/`
        <h1> About </h1>
        <button id="myBtn" type="button" >Try it</button> 

        <script>
            document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener ("click",  ${myFunction})
        </script>
    `
    }
}

export default About;
```

This transforms to the HTML code;

```
<div id="page_container" class="container pageEntry">
        <h1> About </h1>
        <button id="myBtn" type="button">Try it</button> 

        <script>
            document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener ("click",  () => {

    console.log('Yo');
    alert('Yo');

})
        </script>
    </div>
```

However on clicking on the button, nothing happens;

---

I am trying to work on a basic vanilla js SPA and I have hit a problem where I am unable to call any functions in my current module from the html code. I am using the es6 modules by specifying in my index.html that script tag is of type="module".

For example, in this code, i have tried both the inline onclick tag attribute as well as adding an event listener (i used one at a time, not together. showing it here just for illustration)

```
let myFunction = () => {
    console.log('Yo');
    alert('Yo');
}

let About = {

    render : async () => {

        return /*html*/`
        <h1> About </h1>
        <button id="myBtn" type="button" onclick="${myFunction}">Try it</button> 

        <script>
        document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener ("click",  myFunction()})
        </script>
    `
    }
}

export default About;
```

and I consume the resultant view as

```
content.innerHTML = await page.render();
```

from my main module.

The only way I am able to do this is by having my function call return yet another template containng the actual JS code.

```
let myFunction = () => {
    return `
        alert('Yo');
        document.getElementById('myBtn').textContent = 'Duh'
        `
}
```

however, this creates a very ugly page where my entire JS code is added inline into the HTML and that I can no longer use double quotes in my js code.

Comment: Why do you need a template literal at all here? Can't you just do `onclick="myFunction()"` or `addEventListener("click", myFunction)`? (Note for the latter you pass the function object itself, not a call to it.)

Comment: If i do `onclick="${myFunction()}`, it runs the code immediately. If I do, onclick="${myFunction}, nothing happens on click. myFunction in both cases is `let myFunction = () => {
    alert('Yo');
}`

Comment: No, I meant drop the backticks and the `$` signs, just have a literal string of HTML, including `onclick="myFunction()"` (escaping quotes if needed). Since it seems `myFunction` is the only function that you ever want to run here. Template literals are a way to embed the values of expressions inside strings, much easier than using literal strings and expressions with `+` inbetween them - but for this reason they're only useful if the content might change according to context.

Comment: In that case, it is never able to find the myFunction func. It gives a `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`

Comment: oh I see, it must be that `myFunction` isn't in global scope. In that case then `onClick` won't work at all. Nor will `addEventListener` if it's executed from a `<script>` tag that you're inserting on the page. I still don't think a template literal is the way to solve this - I'd say you're better off making the `addEventListener` call just after you've inserted the HTML, and making sure `myFunction` is in scope there. Hard to know how to do it without knowing more about your code - but I'm pretty sure this isn't the kind of problem template literals were designed to solve.

Comment: Why are you using `async`/`await`? There's nothing asynchronous about your code.

Comment: What is the `html` that you commented out?

Comment: This is just a sample code. my view fetches data from an api and the displays the transformed data. The HTML is a template literal tag which is for my vscode extension. it formats the es6 literals as a proper HTML code.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I have indeed tried calling the addevent listerener from a script tag. I didnt know I wasn't supposed to do that. I have added another example in my question of how i went about it.

Comment: @RishavSharan you can do it, no problem - but the function you're referencing to use as an event listener has to be in scope when you make the call. In your script tag, that means it will need to be in global scope - which I'm now assuming it isn't. (That's good design to avoid global variables/functions - but you still need to take care you only references variables and functions which are in scope.)

Comment: and having seen the edit, if that HTML you have posted is the actual HTML used on the page, that should work.(A `<script>` inside a div looks weird to me, but it seems it's actually valid HTML.) Are you sure that's actually what's getting output? (Have you checked the page source?)

Comment: The page source doesn't show the js generated content. but the web tools node elements show the generated html. I copy pasted from there. I think the event listener is not getting added for some reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out my problem with the help of another forum.

"Scripts inserted into innerHTML don't run. You should try splitting the render function into render and onMount - the second one called just after the innerHTML line."

Architecting my app into;

```
let About = {
    render : async () => {
        let view =  /*html*/
            `
            <h1> About </h1>
            <button id="myBtn" type="button" >Try it</button> 
            `
        return view
    },
    after_render: async () => {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener ("click",  () => {
            console.log('Yo')
            alert('Yo')
        })
    }

}

export default About;
```

and consuming it as;

```
content.innerHTML = await page.render();
await page.after_render();
```

solved my problems.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how you can invoke a function in a template literal:

```js
const func = () => 'Hello'

console.log(`${func()} World`)
```

Comment: That's incorrect, it inserts the return value of the function, not the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can give the onClick a reference to your function, by not providing the `()` when referencing it. This will tell JavaScript to call the function and attempt to pass it the event's arguments when it gets triggered.

```
onclick=`${myFunction}`
```

will get called everytime the element is clicked.